# the order of values appearing in the drop down getting changed

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, stringbuffer

I have an arraylist of values that are sorted both **numerically and alphabetically**. For eg. the list has values(in same order) like  **1, 2, 5, 10, 100, A012B, AB, XY, Z**.

Im adding this list to a StringBuffer using a for loop and returning the Stringbuffer object as a string (via `sbf.toString()`) since my method can return only String type (as per method declaration). I cannot change the return type (it has to be a String since my framework accepts only String type).

The values that are returned are displayed in a dropdown. But the order of values is getting changed and being displayed like **1, 10, 100, 2, 5, A012B, AB, XY, Z**. I want the values to be displayed in the same fashion that they were present in the arraylist. Can you help?

Comment: That's not possible. `StringBuffer` doesn't impose any special ordering on appended strings. Appended strings come out in order. Please post your loop.

Comment: This is a problem of a code that populate the `dropdown` control

Comment: And you could easily have seen for yourself that it isn't the StringBuffer doing that. In the light of these comments I strongly recommend you edit your title to reflect the real problem. If you want a solution.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I changed my title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that is adding data to the dropdown appears to be sorting the data.  How do you create the dropdown list?  Is this a Swing application or a web application? In some web-frameworks, dropdown lists are automatically sorted and you have to disable that default in this case.

StringBuffer will not sort a string automatically, so that can't be the problem.  To test this, output the StringBuffer contents to the command-line just before adding it to the list.

Comment: I tested that and it showed correct ordering as per my expectation(i.e 1,2,5,10,100,A012B,AB,XY,Z). I am using a framework called 'enovia' and this code is written in it. I am not sure whether the framework is "String" sorting the data back.

Comment: I've never worked with 'enovia' so I can't say for sure what it does. The framework has to split the String somehow to make it work in a drop-down list, so that must be when it decides to sort the contents. Do you have a link to the documentation for the version of the framework you are using?

Comment: found the solution to my problem some days ago. The problem is not with my program. There is another sort function in the display program of the 'enovia' framework which is re-sorting the values alphabetically and displaying them. Fixed the issue now. Thanks for your comments

Comment: That is interesting, so the framework was making a decision to sort the data all by itself. Great, I'm glad you caught it - makes one think about all the magic that happens in the background with these frameworks.

Comment: yes, glad that I got it. But its your idea that made me think on those lines. Thanks once again